# What is causing Excel Run time error '6' overflow?

Tags: excel, vba

Please can someone help me to correct my code to eliminate the overflow error I get when there is only one cell that meets the selection criteria in my code below? Cell A4 and down contains a description of a product and cell B4 and down contain a quantity. The intent is to copy the description from A4 to column L as many times as corresponds to the quantity in B4 and to repeat this process as many times as there are product descriptions in column A. This works perfectly when there is more than one description to be copied, but results in an overflow error if A5 downwards are empty. The three macros being called in the code below are - I believe - all innocuous and have only to do with unprotecting this worksheet before the real code starts to run and then to format a range and re-protect the worksheet once done.
I am pretty decent with Excel formulas, but my coding is weak, so I am hoping the answer is a simple flaw in my code. Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Create_NumberList()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Selections").Select
    Call UnprotectSelections
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim x, MyCount As Integer

    lRow = Range("A4:B4").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each cell In Range("A4:A" & lRow)
        cell.Copy
        MyCount = cell.Offset(0, 8)

        Do
            x = x + 1
            Range("L" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                 :=False, Transpose:=False
            MyCount = MyCount - 1
        Loop Until MyCount = 0
    Next cell

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ProtectSelections
    Call ReformatSelections
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `lRow = Range("A4:B4").End(xlDown).Row`

To: `lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row`

The reason is that if `A5:B5` and on down are all empty, `lRow` becomes the very bottom in the spreadsheet with the `xlDown` function, and the variables cannot hold the memory for the row numbers (and the code also loops needlessly).

So, if the code starts at the bottom and looks up (with `xlUp`) it will also find the last row of data to check.

Comment: Scott, that not only works perfectly but has noticeably sped up the VBA process! I'd also like to mention that this is the second time that you have provided me with a great solution and I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @user1483720 - that was like 4 years ago! Amazing! Also, it's best practice on SO to accept the answers that work for you or you find useful so that others can benefit going forward.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that. It's not very intuitive if you're not a regular user.